# Implementar un ProgressBar al cargar una DataGridview

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015

Trabajo con Visual Studio 2015, Windows Forms

Tengo la necesidad de poner un progressBar mientras cargo una grilla de la siguiente manera.

```
private void LoadCargarXml(string path)
    {
        string[] ficheros = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml");


        //List<ArchivoXml> lista = new List<ArchivoXml>();
        foreach (var item in ficheros)
        {
            _lista.Add(new ArchivoXml()
            {
                Ruta = item,
                Nombre = Path.GetFileName(item) 
            });
        }

        dgvXml.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgvXml.DataSource = _lista;
        Utilidades.AutoGenerateRowNumber(dgvXml);
        Utilidades.FormatoDgv(dgvXml);
        ChangeWidthColumnXml();
    }
```

Llamo a este método desde un evento.

Implementación

```
private void LoadCargarXml(string path)
    {
        string[] ficheros = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml");

        int progreso = 0;
        progressBarCargaGrilla.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
        progressBarCargaGrilla.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 10;
        progressBarCargaGrilla.Maximum = ficheros.Length;
        progressBarCargaGrilla.Visible = true;

        foreach (var item in ficheros)
        {
            progreso++;
            progressBarCargaGrilla.Value = progreso;

            _lista.Add(new ArchivoXml()
            {
                Ruta = item,
                Nombre = Path.GetFileName(item)
            });
           Application.DoEvents();
        }

        dgvXml.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgvXml.DataSource = _lista;
        Utilidades.AutoGenerateRowNumber(dgvXml);
        Utilidades.FormatoDgv(dgvXml);
        ChangeWidthColumnXml();
        progressBarCargaGrilla.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Sabes cuantos datos tendrás que cargar en la DataGridview?

Comment: @Aritzbn No puede ser n cantidades.

Comment: si no tienes el número de elementos que quieres cargar antes de empezar la carga, creo que lo mejor sería poner una [barra de carga](https://media.giphy.com/media/kR0hPQseayvjq/giphy.gif).

Comment: @Aritzbn Bueno si puedo saber el numero de elementos

Comment: Puedes hacer algo tipo `ProgressBar.Maximum = numero_de_elementos` y luego en cada vuelta del bucle hacer `ProgressBar.Increment(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo mejor sera que utilices un backgroundworker y mostrar un gif de carga hasta que el backgroundworker termine de cargar el datagridview inclusive puedes hacerlo con lambda

de esta manera

```
BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
            this.Enabled = false;
            imagen.Visible = true;
            bg.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
            {
                //Carga y llenado de tu grid
                //probablemente aqui tengas que hacer un invoke al hilo
            };
            bg.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) =>
            {
               OnCompleted();
            };
            bg.RunWorkerAsync();
```

y hacemos una funcion void para volver a habilitar y desaparecer la imagen esto para no tener que hacer el invoke del hilo.

```
private void OnCompleted() {
        this.Enabled = true;
        imagen.Visible = false;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Si bien podrias poner un `ProgressBar` mientras iteras los archivos en el `foreach`, no creo que refleje todo el trabajo ya que no se estaria incluyendo la operacion que carga esta lista en el grid, es por eso que recomendaria muestres un progresbar con el `style` como `marquee`, entonces reflejas trabajo pero no un avance real.

```
ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
```

indicando ademas la propiedad para definir la velocidad el movimiento

[ProgressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.progressbar.marqueeanimationspeed?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Como no vas a realizar la operacion dentro de un `thread` porque todo implica acceso a controles de la UI, deberias intercalar en el codigo la linea

[Application.DoEvents](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.doevents?view=netframework-4.7.2)

de esta forma liberas el `thread` para que la `progressbar` se pueda actualizar visualmente y no quede la pantalla congelada

Esta linea la podrias poner dentro del `foreach` y ademas antes de asignar los datos al `datagridview`, la idea es liberar el thread en varios puntos para que el progress pueda actualizarse

Comment: No me muestra la barra de progreso, voy a actualizar el hilo inicial con la implemntación.

Comment: que pasa si lo dejas siempre visible? o pones un Application.DoEvents() antes de iniciar el foreach. Ademas si defines el Style Marquee del progress no tienes que asignar ningun Value, no vas a mostrar un avance real, sera solo un movimiento continua basado en la speed